# Find and delete/replace a part of bigger string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

In my python/Django project, I am trying to write a custom exception class where I want to avoid showing few things to the end user.

In the below error message, if you see the project name `prj-eng-d-nc-prcd-1077` is appearing. I want to remove that before the message goes to UI.

I was trying to do find and replace. For ex:

```
prj_name = 'prj-eng'
if prj_name in msg:
  msg = msg.replace(prj_name, '')

print (msg)
```

But the problem here is project name will be dynamic. It could be `prj-eng-h-nc-raw-1637` or `prj-eng-p-nc-oauth-2218`.

I was also trying to use rfind() where we can find the start of the substring and replace, but that did not help.

Can anyone please help me with the solution.

```
    {
        "jobs": [],
        "error": "Unable to process the request",
        "msg": "400 Bad int64 value: prj-eng-d-nc-prcd-1077\n\nLocation: us-central1\nJob ID: f8fc4fde-280b-4f35-ae9e-5fb92d2d0873\n" 
}
```

Input would be :

```
msg = "400 Bad int64 value: prj-eng-d-nc-prcd-1077\n\nLocation: us-central1\nJob ID: f8fc4fde-280b-4f35-ae9e-5fb92d2d0873\n"
```

Output should be :

```
msg =  "400 Bad int64 value: \n\nLocation: us-central1\nJob ID: f8fc4fde-280b-4f35-ae9e-5fb92d2d0873\n"
```

Comment: You should look into the python regular expression package https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a dynamic sub-string from a string in a custom exception class, you can use regular expressions to match the sub-string and replace it with an empty string.

```
import re

class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        # Remove project name from error message
        project_name_pattern = r'prj-eng(-\w+)*-\d+'
        self.msg = re.sub(project_name_pattern, '', msg)
```

#Example

```
try:
    raise CustomException('400 Bad int64 value: prj-eng-d-nc-prcd-1077\n\nLocation: us-central1\nJob ID: f8fc4fde-280b-4f35-ae9e-5fb92d2d0873\n')
except CustomException as e:
    print(e.msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Python's [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Using `re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)`, we can substitute the `pattern` with the `replacement` in the `string`.

The following code demonstrates its use, provided `prj-eng-d-nc` part remains the same.

```py
import re

msg = "text before prj-eng-d-nc-raw-1637 text after"
pattern = r"prj-eng-d-nc-\w*-\d*"
# replacing the pattern with empty string if matched
msg = re.sub(pattern, "", msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

One example l for a solution without regex magic:

```
msg = "400 Bad int64 value: prj-eng-d-nc-prcd-1077\n\nLocation: us-central1\nJob ID: f8fc4fde-280b-4f35-ae9e-5fb92d2d0873\n"

start = "400 Bad int64 value:"
end = "\n\nLocation:"

# find the index
front = msg.find(start)+len(start)
back = msg.find(end)

# slice via index
new_msg = msg[:front] + msg[back+1:]
print(new_msg)
```

Output:

```
400 Bad int64 value:
Location: us-central1
Job ID: f8fc4fde-280b-4f35-ae9e-5fb92d2d0873
```

Or you can print in one line with  `print(repr(new_msg))`.